# How to validate Select value with Yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, yup

i'm having a problem with yup in my form, i'm using react, material ui and yup for validations. In my form i have some input value that are working fine with the validations, but with the select i'm receiving the required alert when an option is selected and i don´t know if i'm doing something wrong.
This is my yup schema, the value with the problem is plan:
[image]

The form contains inputs and a text field with the select function, here i'm showing the data:

[image]

when i submit my data, this works fine, all the values are sent to the database, but i need to validate that the select value in plan is correct and no empty. But if i put the required in my yup, the message appears all the time, with a value or not.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing `value` and `onChange` props.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i don´t see any change after remove value and onChange props. The error message continue